# Outlook2013 What's the control Id for New and Delete

Tags: outlook-addin

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to add another group in between these 2 groups, But I couldn't find the control Id for any of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of built-in control IDs in the following documents:

- [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)
- [Office 2010 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)

Answer (score 0):

I found it, they are GroupMailNew and GroupMailDelete.